# Copy a PGSQL result Query to a MYSQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I need some guidance from you on the best way to do the following:

I have 2 separate servers:

- Server 1 (Windows): Windows + PGSQL application
- Server 2 (Linux): PHP + MySQL application

I need to take, with some frequency, the result of a query for from Server 1 to Server 2. This query returns a few thousand results.

I tried to use the following script in PHP to export the data from PGSQL to CSV and then import it on the MySQL server.

```
  $PGcon = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); $MySQLcon = mysqli_connect("$MySQlHost", "$MySQLDB", "$MySQLDBPWD", "$MySQLDB") or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); $sql="COPY (SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE ...) TO '/var/www/html/mycsv.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;" $PGResult = pg_query($con, $sql) or die("Cannot execute query: $sql\n");
```

but I always have the following error:

Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: could not open file "/var/www/html/mycsv.csv" for writing: No such file or directory

I have already modified the permissions of the mycsv.csv file and changed the owner of the file to the apache user.

Do you have any idea what it might be? Or do you suggest another approach?

Comment: `COPY` is a *Postgres* server command. The Postgres service needs to be able to access that file not the web server. If `/var/www/html/mycsv.csv` does exist, check that the Postgres service has write access to it. If that still doesn't help check if it can read and change into all the directories along the path (I'm not sure whether this is really needed, so that's a "just in case"). Check if that is to no avail too, check if the Postgres service is in a `chroot` jail or maybe the web server is. Translate the path accordingly if necessary.

Comment: (And as a side note, probably use some newlines in your code. It would be easier to read.)

Comment: Oh and if the Postgres service also runs on the Windows machine (it's not clear, from you post, if only a client application runs there) `/var/www/html/mycsv.csv` would probably translate to something like `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\var\www\html\mycsv.csv` or `%HOMEDRIVE%\var\www\html\mycsv.csv` (as seen by the user the Postgres service runs under), in a standard configuration probably `C:\var\www\html\mycsv.csv`. So that has to be accessible then, not the path on the other machine.

Comment: Yes the Postgres runs on Windows machine.  It will be difficult to use the Postgres copy command, because I am invoking from another server. I was thinking about trying to generate the CSV file and download it on-the-fly through the PHP script.